# Firebase analytics - missing debugview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm implementing firebase analytics and would like to see the events logged in the firebase console immediately. This should be possible in the [debugview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) but it's not visible in my console.

**What do I need to do in order to add the debugview?**

Debugview as seen in [firebase keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zssCC6rXyGk&feature=youtu.be&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmYSsW6ED2QvHxuI3UzT0WZ&t=1367)
[image: debugview as seen in]

My firebase console
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DebugView is currently only available to a limited set of developers. If will be made generally available soon (I don't have any details on the exact date though).

If you *have* been invited to join the early access program, but it isn't showing in the Console, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so we can help you troubleshoot.

If you *haven't* been invited to join that early access program, DebugView correctly won't show in your console. Hint: I highly recommend you read [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html) in that case.

Comment: In that case I think the litte blue box in top of https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview should be in bold red

Answer (score 0):

Now Firebase Debug view is available .
You have to set your devices a prop using adb command . 
If you are using emulator take care to have the latest version of play services .

Answer (score -1):

Check out your GoogleService-Info.plist file if **IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED** property is true.

Comment: This property isn't related to Firebase, but to Google Analytics for Apps, as is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection)